# React Native FlatList scroll event doesn't work

Tags: react-native

This is my structure. Inside  is a tab view with 3 screens. Each screen has a FlatList, the problem is here, the onEndReached of FlatList cannot be triggered ...

```
<ScrollView
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
    endFillColor='#fff'
>
    <AddrTop address={address} />
    <HomeInput />     
    <Carousel />
    <TabBar />
    <MemberBenefit />
    <PreferentialArea />
    <HomeList /> 
</ScrollView>
```

HomeList , use react-native-tab-view

```
  <TabView
            navigationState={{index, routes}}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            onIndexChange={setIndex}
            renderTabBar={TabBar}
            lazy
            removeClippedSubviews
        />
```

screen

```
  <FlatList
            style={{marginTop: 5}}
            data={list}
            renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem data={item} />}
            keyExtractor={((item, index) => index.toString())}
            onEndReached={() =>console.log('cannot trigger)}
        />
```

Comment: You are using a FlatList inside a ScrollView. I think that's the problem here.

Comment: I also think this is the cause, but is there a solution? Without ScrollView, <HomeList /> will be hidden ... @aytek

Comment: Change the structure of your page and use only one Flastlist or a SectionList. And put all your components inside that. And don't forget to get rid of the ScrollView

Comment: @aytek is right. don't place flatlist inside scrollview

Answer (score 0):

As per React-Native [Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onendreached), `onEndReached` is called once `when the scroll position gets within onEndReachedThreshold of the rendered content.`

So, you'll need to add `onEndReachedThreshold` as well.

Something like

```
<FlatList
    onEndReached={() => console.log('onEndReached')}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have tried it before, but it has no effect ..